# Switching view/view model based on a parameter

Tags: wpf, catel

In a wpf application I've to show different filter user control based on a parameter passed to the main view model.  Each filter's view model  implements IReportFilter and the main view model has a property of type

```
IReportFilter Filters {get;set;}
```

How do I resolve the correct xaml view?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use a base class instead of IReportFilter? Normally you need not to have abstraction between View & ViewModels as they are inseparable.

Comment: Well baseclass /interface does not resolve on the xaml side how I load an user control based on the parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a base class instead of IReportFilter,say ReportFilter.
Follow the below steps:
1. Define DataTemplate For Filter1VM & Filter2VM & set the usercontrols.
Note that I have naming conventions while defining the control & VMs.

```
<DataTemplate DataType={x:type viewModels:Filter1VM}>
<usercontrols:Filter1/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType={x:type viewModels:Filter2VM}>
<usercontrols:Filter2/>
</DataTemplate>
```

2. You need to define a custom DataTemplateSelector.

```
class CustomDataTemplateSelector:DataTemplateSelector
{
  public ovverride DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item,....)
  {
    Type t=item.GetType();
    string typename=t.Name;
    string viewName=typeName.Replace("VM",String.Empty);
    DataTemplate dt=App.Current.Resources[viewname] as DataTemplate;
    return dt;
  }
}
```

3.Define a property TemplateSelector in ReportFilter class & initialise it in constructor as:

```
TemplateSelector=new CustomDataTemplateSelector();
```

4. In your window's VM, create ReportFilter Filter property:

```
ReportFilter Filter {get;set;}
```

5. In your application Window,add ContentControl where you need to place the filterControl:

   ContentControl Content="{Binding Filter}"
          ContentTemplateSelector="{Binding Filter.TemplateSelector}"
6. In your window's view model, assing Filter as Filter1VM/Filter2VM based on the parameter passed.

Comment: Since the template selector is something that belongs to the UI, I prefer to define that as static resource in the view instead. The rest looks good!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SomeContent}"/>
```

Then in viewmodel create two controls for your needs and simply switch them based on your filter

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to create controls in ViewModel then you can do the following for example:

```
<Grid>
    <Column / Rows Definitions>
<YourControl1 Grid.Row="X" Grid.Column="Y" IsVisible={Binding BoolFilter1, Converter={StaticResource Bool2Visibility}/>
<YourControl1 Grid.Row="X" Grid.Column="Y" IsVisible={Binding BoolFilter2, Converter={StaticResource Bool2Visibility}/>
....
</Grid>
```

Comment: View model is not meant to create controls. Instead you need to define DataTemplate for the ViewModel.

Comment: I've updated answer if you don't want to create controls in code behind

Comment: Are you suggesting to add all possible filter usercontrols in UI ?